# AngularJS orderBy example function not working

Tags: angularjs

Is it flaw or is it expected to work like this?

Initally the sort order is set in the controller

```
$scope.order('-age',false);
```

and in the view,

```
<a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('age',reverse)">Age</a>
```

We need to click twice on the "age" column in order to get it sorted!

Following are the steps I followed,

1. Load the example link.
2. Click once column age

Expected Result : 
   "age" column should be sorted

Actual Result : 
"age" column doesn't get sorted on 1st click but does on 2nd click;

Is it right behavior?

[LINK TO EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6RerZq2eE0igLQsrxQc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial sort to boolean `true`:

```
$scope.order('-age', true);
```

#### [Link to Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ddUnb3tXawCES2Q6RG4?p=preview)

Comment: I wanted the values to be loaded in ascending order; And later sort;